# Drop down with options as incremental numbers up to a certain number

Tags: lightning-aura-components, pagination

```
<aura:attribute name="totalPages" type="Integer"/>     
<lightning:select name="select1" label="How many tickets?">
                                    <aura:iteration items = "{v.totalPages}" >
                                    <option value="">choose one...</option>
                                    </aura:iteration>
                                </lightning:select>
```

I want to make a drop down for pagination, where I have totalPages aura attribute that will contain how many pages, for example 5.
Then I want the drop down menu, the lightning select component, to have options 1,2,3,4,5. Is there a way to do it without having to do some math and configuration on js controller and saving it as an array?

Answer (score 2):

aura:iteration iterates over a collection of items; you can't use it for iteration without providing a collection.

If you want to accomplish this without JavaScript, and there's a reasonably small maximum number of elements (e.g. 20), then you can create a default collection and short-circuit the loop when it's passed the provided number of pages

```
<aura:attribute name="totalPages" type="Integer"/>     
<aura:attribute name="pageNumbers" type="Integer[]" default="[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]" />

<lightning:select name="select1" label="How many tickets?">
  <option value="">choose one...</option>

  <aura:iteration items="{v.pageNumbers}" var="pageNumber" >
    <aura:if isTrue="{!pageNumber < v.totalPages}">
      <option value="{!pageNumber}">Page {!pageNumber}</option>
    </aura:if>
  </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

Note, all of the hard-coded text here (e.g. "Page {0}", "How many tickets?" etc.) should be converted to custom labels, to allow for translation. But that's another subject.

EDIT: as sfdcfox has pointed out, this really should be done with JavaScript so that it can handle pages of any length; the above code meets the requirement of no JavaScript, but fails if there are 21 or more pages.

For a Javascript version, here's the code for the component and controller, respectively:

```
<aura:attribute name="totalPages" type="Integer" />     
<aura:attribute name="pages"      type="Object[]" />

<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.totalPages}" action="{!c.handleTotalPagesChanged}" />

<lightning:select name="select1" label="How many tickets?">
  <option value="">choose one...</option>

  <aura:iteration items="{v.pages}" var="page" >
    <option value="{!page.Number}">Page {!page.Number}</option>
  </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

```js
(
  handleTotalPagesChanged: function handleTotalPagesChanged(cmp, event, helper) {
    let pages      = [],
        totalPages = cmp.get('v.totalPages') || 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < totalPages; i++) {
      pages.push({ Number : i + 1 });
    }

    cmp.set('v.pages', pages);
  }
)
```

Using an object as an element of the array allows you to store other information related to a particular page. You don't always need this structure up front, but I've found it to be a good design habit to always allow for more data points, as business requirements change.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I would prefer generating the list on the fly, perhaps in response to a change in the data, so that it doesn't matter if it's 1 page or 1000, it'll just work.

Comment: Wow, I got a comment from a celebrity! Your comments all over the internet are a huge part of how I've learned Salesforce the last few years -- thanks for taking the time :-).

As for this solution, it's definitely a hack so Peter can avoid using JavaScript. But the whole point of lightning is to use JavaScript, so I also would just generate the list dynamically in JS instead of doing this, lol.